# setColor is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am using discord.js and I wanted to create an embed message but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: (intermediate value).setColor(...).setTitle(...).setUrl is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\oussa\OneDrive\Bureau\Discord Bot\index.js:48:10)
    at Client.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\oussa\OneDrive\Bureau\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\oussa\OneDrive\Bureau\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\oussa\OneDrive\Bureau\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\oussa\OneDrive\Bureau\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\oussa\OneDrive\Bureau\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\oussa\OneDrive\Bureau\Discord Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\oussa\OneDrive\Bureau\Discord Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:797:20)
```

I couldn't do it here is my code and I am using v12

```js
bot.on('message', (message) => {
 const BanEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('#5300A6')
  .setTitle('title me me title')
  .setAuthor('bla bla')
  .setDescription('bla bla')
  .setFooter('footer');

 if (message.content == 'test') {
  message.channel.send(BanEmbed);
 }
});
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! I am not an expert here, but it looks like that a setUrl is mandatory.

Comment: Do you perhaps need to call `.setURL()` on your `BanEmbed` object? Here's an example I found from Discord: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-richembedmessageembed-constructor

Comment: Documentation for `setURL` itself: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setURL

Answer (score 0):

The error isn't that `setColor` is not a function but rather that `setUrl` is not a function.

From the looks of this Discord example: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-richembedmessageembed-constructor it looks like calling `.setURL()` is required when creating an instance of `MessageEmbed`.

Try the following:

```
  const BanEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#5300A6')
        .setTitle('title me me title')
        .setAuthor('bla bla')
        .setDescription('bla bla')
        .setFooter('footer')
        .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
```

You could probably substitute your own embed url for the one above.

Answer (score 0):

There are no errors in the code you've provided, so I guess you've used another code? The error is that you wrote something like `.setUrl("http://example.com/")`. It has to be .setURL with uppercase URL.

This embed would work and make your title a link to http://example.com/.

```
const BanEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#5300A6')
    .setTitle('title me me title')
    .setAuthor('bla bla')
    .setDescription('bla bla')
    .setFooter('footer')
    .setURL('http://example.com')
```

[image]